# How does certification work to reach a secured web service?

Tags: java, php, certificate

I need to reach a java based web service which is reachable only for certified connections.
On my side, the technologie is PHP.

So, I have to send my certificate signing request to the the certification authority.
I was told that I have to use these instructions :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, "file1"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, "file2");
```

My questions are : What are the "file1" and "file2" ? What will do exactly (unix commands) the certification authority with my certificate request ?

Regards,

Pat.

Answer (score 0):

file1 and file2 are the file directories of the certificate-file (file1) and the key-file (file2)

For more information on `curl_setopt()` check this manual: [click](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)